# Shouldn't Elliot have been caught or at least noticed outside of the prison?

Tags: plot-explanation, realism, mr-robot

I don't know what's considered a spoiler, so I'll put more than probably necessary in a spoiler block...

At the end of episode 1.5 of *Mr. Robot*, Elliot and Vera's brother are standing outside of the prison waiting for Vera to come out.

> After the prison doors open and the prisoners begin to escape, there's a really obvious lack of police. I know Elliot mentioned that there was a 2 minute delay before sirens went off, but even when they do go off and we start to hear sirens and police, we don't see them. Not only that, but Elliot, Vera, Isaac, and DJ stood around for an awfully long time about 20 meters from the prison gate.

Wouldn't they have been caught?

Comment: I think the cops were more concerned with those in orange jumpsuits running away from the prison than those close by.  Yes they probably should have been caught, but they were in the eye of the storm, as it were, with a lot of commotion and activity going on around them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The logical answer is yes, they should have been caught.  [Suspension of disbelief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspension_of_disbelief) is a common narrative technique. As both of our beliefs didn't quite get extended far enough in this scene, an answer could be that they simply failed to "sell it".

However, Eliot's tenuous grip on reality is a major element of the show, so it's possible some or all of that story-line was imagined. Eliot's fingerprints and DNA were all over the place, after all.

The literal explanation is probably that the chaos caused by the hack was sufficient to allow them to escape. Since Eliot has never been arrested, so far as we know, his fingerprints wouldn't be on file anywhere.

Comment: Isn't Elliot seeing the psychologist on a court order (at least initially)?  And if so, wouldn't that require his prints to be in the system?

Comment: It is unclear at this point as to whether he was actually arrested over that incident or if it was more of a civil suit over destruction of property (i.e. the servers he trashed when his co-workers locked him in the server room.)  But you raise a very good point!

Answer (score 3):

I've got another possible explanation after the events that happened in Ep 5 of Season 2.

> He did.  In this episode, he is shown to actually be in prison.  My theory is that he did get caught but was given a light sentence based on how he ended up involved (perhaps a small drug charge rather than murder).  100% of elliots's story line since that point has been fabricated in his head.